# RocksDB with jemalloc or tcmalloc in KafkaStreams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb, tcmalloc, jemalloc

My KafkaStreams apps run as Docker images in Kubernetes cluster and thus had to configure the pods to contain `jemalloc` and `tcmalloc`. By adding

```bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2
# or 
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4
```

the standard glibc memory allocator will be overridden, but it doesn't work as expected:

- with `jemalloc` the streams stall in rebalancing state and
- with `tcmalloc` the override just doesn't happen.

Did anyone successfully use either of these with Kafka Streams?